# How can I debug a form?

Tags: html, debugging

I'd like to see what a website is sending when I submit a form.
Using Firebug I can see that it is regular POST form.
I'm interested in the coding of the form fields.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there already. Just go to the "Net" tab in firebug (you may have to enable it by click the small arrow next to the word "Net"), and then submit the form. The Net tab will catch the post and show you the headers in the "Headers" section and the actual post data in the "Post" section.

Answer (score 1):

[Temperdata](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/966) is a great tool for that in firefox.

Comment: Hope I didnt misunderstand your question... :)

Comment: No, you didn't.   
Temperdata would definetly do the job, but as I already use Firebug, it is easier with it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you meant **server-side** coding, you can not see that, you can only see html.